# React Native <TextInput> hides text onBlur for Android

Tags: android, react-native

In my React Native app, I have a  that I want to add a style to when it is focused (change textAlign from 'center' to 'left'). It works fine in iOS, but it seems like on Android, updating the TextInput's style prop from the onBlur callback makes the TextInput's text disappear.

Here's my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      inputText: '',
      inputStyle: {},
      inputStyleOnFocus: styles.input_focused
    }
  }
  onFocusInput = () => {
    this.setState({inputStyle: this.state.inputStyleOnFocus})
  }
  onBlurInput = () => {
    this.setState({inputStyle: {}})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior='padding'>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Text from input: { this.state.inputText }</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={[styles.input, this.state.inputStyle]}
          placeholder='Type something'
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({inputText: text})}
          onFocus={this.onFocusInput}
          onBlur={this.onBlurInput}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 100
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
    minWidth: 200
  },
  input_focused: {
    textAlign: 'left'
  }
});
```

Here's a link to an Expo Snack:
https://snack.expo.io/@timathis/textinput-onblur-hides-text-for-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not store style in the state. Just have a flag in the state. And in the render method, apply styles according to the value of the flag.

EDIT

Try this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      inputText: '',
      applyAditionalStyles: false,
    }
  }
  onFocusInput = () => {
    this.setState({applyAditionalStyles: true})
  }
  onBlurInput = () => {
    this.setState({applyAditionalStyles: false})
  }
  render() {
    const { applyAditionalStyles, inputText } = this.state; 
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior='padding'>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Text from input: { inputText }</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={[styles.input, applyAditionalStyles && styles.input_focused]}
          placeholder='Type something'
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({inputText: text})}
          onFocus={this.onFocusInput}
          onBlur={this.onBlurInput}
          value={inputText}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 100
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
    minWidth: 200
  },
  input_focused: {
    textAlign: 'left'
  }
});
```

All you are missing is `value={inputText}` in your `TextInput` component.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution has the same effect. The text still disappears. It seems like maybe the issue 
 is an Android's <TextInput> rerendering styles. When the style prop changes, the text disappears.

Comment: Which versions (Android, RN etc.) are you using?

Comment: Android 8.1.0, React Native 0.50.4

Comment: hi @TimMathis, I have updated code. Please have a look, I have tested now it is working fine.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!